# memory leak during release of movieplayer

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller

In one of my apps i want to play a video file from local.so iam using the below code for playing the file.

```
-(IBAction)playMovie{

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Myvideo" ofType:@"mov"]];

MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer=[[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:url]autorelease];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:moviePlayer];

moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;
moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;

[self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
[moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
//[moviePlayer release];
}

-(void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification {

MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [notification object];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self      
                                                name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                              object:moviePlayer];
if ([moviePlayer 
     respondsToSelector:@selector(setFullscreen:animated:)])
{
   [moviePlayer.view removeFromSuperview];
}
[moviePlayer release];

}
```

when i go to analyse or do profile for the above code there shows a warning potential leak happening at 2 places i.e,

```
[moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];

//[moviePlayer release];
```

one more is leak is at this part

```
{

  [moviePlayer.view removeFromSuperview];

}
[moviePlayer release]
```

so how to avoid this memory leak.Even i tried giving autorelease the NSURL Line in the begining of the code,when i do autorelease leak wont  happen but video wont play.so how to solve this issue can anyone help??

Answer (score 0):

try this in moviePlayBackDidFinish method, may be it will help

```
 if (videoPlayer) {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:videoPlayer];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification object:videoPlayer];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:MPMovieMediaTypesAvailableNotification object:videoPlayer];
    [videoPlayer pause];
    videoPlayer.initialPlaybackTime = -1;
    [videoPlayer stop];
    [videoPlayer.view removeFromSuperview];
    [videoPlayer release];
    videoPlayer = nil;
}
```